# How to cut down my code? Reduce 16 Java files to only 4?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to cut down the amount of Java classes I have within my project. I have created a routine planner application with multiple days with an EDIT screen to allow the user to edit their routine and a DISPLAY screen for the user to view their routine. The following code are an example of each but if you remember I have one for each day (e.g. MondayRoutineEdit.java, TuesdayRoutineEdit.java......... and the same for MondayRoutineDisplay.java, TuesdayRoutineDisplay.java.........) - I have also included the code for Database and MainMenu

How can I cut this down so I can have just two single files that manage them all:

- RoutineEdit.java
- RoutineDisplay.java

So in total, I would have only FOUR java files managing my project instead of 16.

Main Menu class

```
public class MainMenu extends AppCompatActivity {

private Button mondaybutton, tuesdaybutton, wednesdaybutton, thursdaybutton, fridaybutton, saturdaybutton, sundaybutton;
public int buttonSelectedID;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.mainmenu);

    mondaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mondaybutton);
    tuesdaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.tuesdaybutton);
    wednesdaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wednesdaybutton);
    thursdaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.thursdaybutton);
    fridaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fridaybutton);
    saturdaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saturdaybutton);
    sundaybutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.sundaybutton);

    MediaPlayer mainmenuprompt = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.mainmenuprompt);
    mainmenuprompt.start();;


    // Monday Routine Button
    mondaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Monday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,MondayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Monday Routine");

            MediaPlayer mondayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.mondayroutineselected);
            mondayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Tuesday Routine Button
    tuesdaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Tuesday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,TuesdayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Tuesday Routine");
            MediaPlayer tuesdayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.tuesdayroutineselected);
            tuesdayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Wednesday Routine Button
    wednesdaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Wednesday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,WednesdayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Wednesday Routine");
            MediaPlayer wednesdayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.wednesdayroutineselected);
            wednesdayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Thursday Routine Button
    thursdaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Thursday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,ThursdayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Thursday Routine");
            MediaPlayer thursdayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.thursdayroutineselected);
            thursdayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Friday Routine Button
    fridaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Friday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,FridayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Friday Routine");
            MediaPlayer fridayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.fridayroutineselected);
            fridayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Saturday Routine Button
    saturdaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Saturday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,SaturdayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Saturday Routine");
            MediaPlayer saturdayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.saturdayroutineselected);
            saturdayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Saturday Routine Button
    sundaybutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Sunday");
            Intent i = new Intent(MainMenu.this,SundayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Sunday Routine");
            MediaPlayer sundayroutineselected = MediaPlayer.create(MainMenu.this, R.raw.sundayroutineselected);
            sundayroutineselected.start();
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}
```

Monday Routine Edit class

```
public class MondayRoutineEdit extends AppCompatActivity {

Database myDb;

private Button DisplayRoutineButton;
private Button ClearRoutineButton;

private static int ImageID = 0;

ImageView activityslotlocationa, activityslotlocationb, activityslotlocationc, activityslotlocationd, activityslotlocatione, activityslotlocationf;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.routineeditscreen);

    myDb = new Database(this);

    DisplayRoutineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.displayroutinebutton);
    ClearRoutineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearroutinebutton);

    // Display Routine Button
    DisplayRoutineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Display Schedule");
            Intent i = new Intent(MondayRoutineEdit.this, MondayRoutineDisplay.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Monday Routine Display");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Delete Routine Button
    ClearRoutineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Delete Routine");
            deleteRoutine();
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Routine Deleted");
        }
    });

    // Audio Feedback
    ImageView artactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.artactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer artsoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.art);
    artactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            artsoundeffect.start();
        }
    });

    ImageView bedtimestoryactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.bedtimestoryactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer bedtimestorysoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bedtimestory);
    bedtimestoryactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bedtimestorysoundeffect.start();
        }
    });

    ImageView brushteethactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.brushteethactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer brushteethsoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.brushteeth);
    brushteethactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            brushteethsoundeffect.start();
        }
    });

    ImageView combhairactivity = (ImageView) this.findViewById(R.id.combhairactivityimage);
    final MediaPlayer combhairsoundeffect = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.combhair);
    combhairactivity.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            combhairsoundeffect.start();
        }
    });



    // findViewById
    artactivity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.artactivityimage);
    bedtimestoryactivity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bedtimestoryactivityimage);
    brushteethactivity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.brushteethactivityimage);
    combhairactivity = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.combhairactivityimage);


    activityslotlocationa = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslota);
    activityslotlocationb = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslotb);
    activityslotlocationc = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslotc);
    activityslotlocationd = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslote);
    activityslotlocatione = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslotd);
    activityslotlocationf = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.activitydisplayslotf);

    // Long click listeners
    artactivity.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    bedtimestoryactivity.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    brushteethactivity.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);
    combhairactivity.setOnLongClickListener(longClickListener);


    activityslotlocationa.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocationb.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocationc.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocationd.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocatione.setOnDragListener(dragListener);
    activityslotlocationf.setOnDragListener(dragListener);

    getRoutine();
}

    View.OnLongClickListener longClickListener = new View.OnLongClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View imageLongClickByUser) {
        View.DragShadowBuilder myShadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(imageLongClickByUser);
        imageLongClickByUser.startDragAndDrop(null, myShadowBuilder, imageLongClickByUser, 0);
        //Grab ID so not to re-grab at every comparison
        int selectedImage = imageLongClickByUser.getId();
        //Check which View is clicked on and save globally

        //activities
        if (selectedImage == R.id.artactivityimage)
            ImageID = R.drawable.art;
        else if (selectedImage == R.id.bedtimestoryactivityimage)
            ImageID = R.drawable.bedtimestory;
        else if (selectedImage == R.id.brushteethactivityimage)
            ImageID = R.drawable.brushteeth;
        else if (selectedImage == R.id.combhairactivityimage)
            ImageID = R.drawable.combhair;


        return true;
    }
};

View.OnDragListener dragListener = new View.OnDragListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onDrag(View imageDropped, DragEvent event) {

                    int dragEvent = event.getAction(); //  returns an action type that indicates the state of the drag and drop operation
                    final View view = (View) event.getLocalState(); // Returns the local state object sent to the system as part of the call to startDragAndDrop().
                    switch (dragEvent) {

                        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:

                            ImageView imageOfActivitySlot = (ImageView) imageDropped; //Check if we are dropping onto an imageView
                            if (imageDropped != null) //If the view is not equal to null then...
                                imageOfActivitySlot.setImageResource(ImageID); //Set the resource to be the image picked up earlier

                            MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(MondayRoutineEdit.this, R.raw.whoosh);
                            mymedia.start();

                            boolean routineInserted = myDb.insertNewRoutine(ImageID, currentDay, imageDropped.getId());
                            if (routineInserted) {
                    Toast.makeText(MondayRoutineEdit.this, "Activity Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(MondayRoutineEdit.this, "Activity Not Inserted", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
        }

        return true;
    }
};

private void getRoutine() {
    Cursor result = myDb.getRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);

    if (result.getCount() == 0) {

    } else {
        //data found, show on screen
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            int ActivityImage = result.getInt(2);
            int Slot = result.getInt(3);
            ImageView emptySlot = (ImageView) findViewById(Slot);
            emptySlot.setImageResource(ActivityImage);
        }
    }
}

private void deleteRoutine() {
    myDb.deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    startActivity(intent);

    MediaPlayer mymedia = MediaPlayer.create(MondayRoutineEdit.this, R.raw.clearroutine);
    mymedia.start();
}
}
```

Monday Display Routine Class

```
public class MondayRoutineDisplay extends AppCompatActivity {
private Button EditRoutineButton;
private Button MainMenuButton;

Database myDb;
private String currentDay = "monday";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.routinedisplayscreen);

    myDb = new Database(this);

    EditRoutineButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.editroutinebutton);
    MainMenuButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mainmenubutton);
    getRoutine();

    // Edit Routine Button
    EditRoutineButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Edit Routine");
            Intent i = new Intent(MondayRoutineDisplay.this, MondayRoutineEdit.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Monday Edit Screen");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });

    // Main Menu Button
    MainMenuButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Log.d("BUTTON CLICKED", "Main Menu");
            Intent i = new Intent(MondayRoutineDisplay.this, MainMenu.class);
            Log.d("SUCCESSFUL", "Loading Main Menu");
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
}

private void getRoutine() {
    Cursor result = myDb.getRoutineForCurrentDay(currentDay);

    if (result.getCount() == 0) {

    } else {
        //data found, show on screen
        while (result.moveToNext()) {
            int ActivityImage = result.getInt(2);
            int Slot = result.getInt(3);
            ImageView emptySlot = (ImageView) findViewById(Slot);
            emptySlot.setImageResource(ActivityImage);
        }
    }
}
}
```

Database class

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "application.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 9;

public static final String RoutineTable = "Routines";
public static final String RoutineColumn1 = "DayOfWeek";
public static final String RoutineColumn2 = "Activity";
public static final String RoutineColumn3 = "Slot";

public Database(Context context)

{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)

{
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE `Routines` (`Routine` INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,`DayOfWeek`   TEXT NOT NULL,`Activity`    INTEGER NOT NULL, `Slot` INTEGER NOT NULL);");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)

{
    onCreate(db);
}

// INSERT OR UPDATE DATA INTO DATABASE
public boolean insertNewRoutine(int activityImage, String selectedDay, int activitySlot)

{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    // db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek ='" + selectedDay + "' AND Slot =" + activitySlot);
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn1,selectedDay);
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn2,activityImage);
    contentValues.put(RoutineColumn3,activitySlot);
    long result = db.insert(RoutineTable, null, contentValues);
    if(result == -1)
        return false;
    else
        return true;
}

// RETRIEVE DATA FROM DATABASE FOR CURRENT DAY
public Cursor getRoutineForCurrentDay(String selectedDay)

{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor result = db.rawQuery("select * from " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek = '" + selectedDay + "'", null);
    return result;
}

// DELETE DATA IN DATABASE FOR CURRENT DAY
public void deleteRoutineForCurrentDay(String selectedDay)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + RoutineTable + " WHERE DayOfWeek ='" + selectedDay + "'");
}
}
```

Comment: The problem you need to solve is not how to collapse all the files into 2 or 4, but how to encapsulate the notion of a weekday and reuse the existing code so that it processes the general notion of a weekday.

Comment: So how would i go about doing that?

Comment: This is, unfortunately, a general question about OO design, which is not going to get much attention. But, the idea is you have data and stuff you want to do to that data. Furthermore, you want to split the classes into separate domains (which you appear to have taken into consideration.) What you need is a UI class of some sort that takes input, and uses that input to invoke methods based on that input. Where you have hard-coded weekdays you would probably want to have a class variable that you pass in as a param to a constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to have a class for each day. Use instead the objective programming properties java is known for. You can simply use a DisplayRoutineClass class and RoutineEdit as an object class. For each day you create an object, ex:

```
RoutineEdit mondayRoutine = new RoutineEdit();
```

and then display objects in your Display class

Comment: So how would i got about changing my code? Sorry abit new to Android and Java :)

Comment: Just like i wrote inte the answer. You create a file with an object RuntineEdit and then assign it different properties for different days. RuntineEdit is basically a datacontainer and the created instances ar independent of each other( not static). You can learn more about classes and objects in java here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_object_classes.htm aswell as in Oracles official documentation.

Comment: Yes but sorry where would I put RoutineEdit MondayRoutine = new RoutineEdit();